# Create ion-tab for specific routes only

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a side menu + tabs layout in ionic structure.

Here is my code for app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova','ngMessages'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: "/register",
        templateUrl: "templates/register.html",
        controller: 'RegistrationCtrl'
    })

    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.search', {
        url: "/search",
        views: {
            'tab-search': {
                templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.browse', {
        url: "/browse",
        views: {
            'tab-browse': {
                templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.playlists', {
        url: "/playlists",
        views: {
            'tab-playlists': {
                templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
                controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.single', {
        url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
        views: {
            'tab-playlists': {
                templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
                controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.about', {
        url: "/about",
        views: {
            'tab-about': {
                templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
                controller: 'AboutCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});

var app = angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state, $cordovaToast, $ionicPlatform,$ionicLoading) {
})

.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
})

.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state, $cordovaToast, $ionicPlatform,$ionicLoading) {
    console.log('Register');
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.playlists = [
        {
            title: 'Reggae',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Chill',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            title: 'Dubstep',
            id: 3
        },
        {
            title: 'Indie',
            id: 4
        },
        {
            title: 'Rap',
            id: 5
        },
        {
            title: 'Cowbell',
            id: 6
        }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {});
```

Here is menu.html which holds the side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <!-- TABS -->
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-assertive">

            <ion-tab title="Search" icon-off="ion-search" icon-on="ion-search" href="#/app/search">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Browse" icon-off="ion-ios-glasses" icon-on="ion-ios-glasses" href="#/app/browse">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-browse"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Playlist" icon-off="ion-ipod" icon-on="ion-ipod" href="#/app/playlists">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <!-- Side Menu (left) -->
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content class="sideMenuImg">
            <div class="profileDisplay">
                <a menu-close href="#/app/profile">
                    <img class="profileImage" src="img/profilePicture.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item class="" menu-close href="#/app/search">
                    <i class='icon ion-home'></i> Dashboard
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="" menu-close href="#/app/browse">
                    <i class='icon ion-calendar'></i> Events
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="" menu-close href="#/app/about">
                    <i class='icon ion-information-circled'></i> About Us
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="" menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    <i class='icon ion-email'></i> Contact Us
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="" menu-close href="#/login">
                    <i class='icon ion-log-out'></i> Logout
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Here I want that About Us page should not have tab layout and only the main view of About should be loaded.

How can I achieve this i.e tabs in the ion-side-menu-content only for specific side menu item and not for all the side menus?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the `About Us` route state can't be a child of the `app` state.

So try changing only the state name:

```
.state('about', {
    url: "/about",
    views: {
        'tab-about': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```